# GLSL PBS implementation, weird shader behaviour

Tags: glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'am using Cook-Torrance specular BRDF + Disney's diffuse BRDF light models, which work fine if applied separately. Unfortunately if I try to combine them something weird happens:
[image: Specular Intensity + Diffuse Intensity artifacts]
Diffuse lightmap looks like this:
[image]
Specular lightmap (notice artifacts on the edge of the terrain):
[image]

Resulting lightmap is being calculated like this:

```
float result = Fr + Fd;
```

Where Fd is a diffuse BRDF component, Fr is a specular BRDF component.

Why does it give such artifacts on the resulting lightmap?

I was thinking that resulting light-intensity exceeds the range [0;1], to check that I modified the code as follows:

```
return result <= 1.0 ? result : 1.0;
```

Resulting lightmap:
[image: Modified shaders]

As you can see, all the artifacts now have an intensity of 1.0 (they obviously exceed [0;1] range), but why does that keep happening if specular map contains zeroes?

Full shader code: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/DxxTvSDm)

Comment: Seems pretty hard to explain. Only time I've ever seen weird results like this from a shader, its been caused by some undefined math which have led to NaN propogating through and breaking stuff in weird ways. 

Perhaps look at all the pow functions and make sure that the first parameter can't be negative by temporarily hacking in an abs/max/saturate or something on all of them (the line pow( pow(dotNH, 2.0) * (m_alpha - 1.0) + 1.0 , 2.0)); might have a negative for example). If that doesn't get it, I'd try simplifyin

Comment: @Columbo Thank you. Dot product of N and L was 0, and it gave division by zero error. I've added abs function as a hotfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Columbo mentioned, it was NaN exception (throwed cause of division by zero), which lead to weird shader behaviour. I modified the code slightly:

```
float F_Schlick (in float f0, in float f90, in float u)
{
    return f0 + ( f90 - f0 ) * pow(clamp(1.0 - u, 0.0, 1.0), 5.0); //line 34
}
```

Dot product should be greater than zero:

```
float dotNV = abs(dot(N, V));
float dotNL = abs(dot(N, L));
```

[The final shader code](http://pastebin.com/GiBvwLcP)